Disappearing texts when scrolling the slider
I have two texts in the view (these texts are parallax)
And a pageView that is like a slider.
When I scroll the slider, the texts disappear and I have to scroll the page again to make them appear!

some notes:
According to the UI, the texts are temporarily off the
page and overflow.
I searched Stack Overflow about this, but I didn't
find anything related to my problem.
I have used CustomScrollview.
This is a web project

- Gif:

SliderCod:
         Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            child: CarouselSlider(
              items: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 400,
                    height: 450,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
              options: CarouselOptions(
                pageSnapping: true,
                viewportFraction: .7,
                autoPlay: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

TextsCod:
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 3000,
            height: 100,
            // color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 56, 56, 56),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: jahat,
            child: Text(
              topText,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              softWrap: true,
              style: TextStyle(
                shadows: [
                  Shadow(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(108, 255, 255, 255),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                  )
                ],
                color: Color.fromARGB(56, 255, 255, 255),
                fontFamily: 'Monum',
                fontSize: 40,
                decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: jahat2,
            top: 45,
            child: Text(
              bittemText,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              softWrap: true,
              style: TextStyle(
                shadows: [
                  Shadow(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(108, 255, 255, 255),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                  )
                ],
                color: Color.fromARGB(190, 255, 255, 255),
                fontFamily: 'Monum',
                fontSize: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


Add your code snippet.

@RavindraS.Patil I don't think it is possible. The codes are long and interrelated, and sharing them causes a lot of volume on the question page.

@Parsa without code snippet, no one can help you, you can add relevant code snap   here.
